# Do all Nexus-6 replicants have enhanced strength?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner, blade-runner-2049

The opening text to *Blade Runner* says that the Nexus-6 replicants have enhanced strength.

> The Nexus-6 replicants were superior in strength and agility, and at least equal in intelligence, to the genetic engineers who created them.

*Blade Runner 2049*’s opening also references this enhanced strength:

> Replicants are bioengineered humans, designed by Tyrell corporation for use off-world. Their enhanced strength made them ideal slave labor.

Do *all* Nexus-6 replicants have enhanced strength?

<sub>I think that this would especially relevant for the “Is Deckard a replicant?” debate, since he would almost certainly be older than Rachael, a Nexus-7 prototype, but he doesn’t seem to have any sort of enhanced strength.</sub>